NextJS App router reusable custom hook for data fetching
I'm currently trying to migrate a project from NextJS pages router to the app router.
In my old project, I had the following structure:
/src
  /components
  /hooks
    customHook.tsx
  /services
    general.ts
  /utils
  /pages
    /api
       /get
          list.ts
    /dashboard
    index.tsx
    ...

Problem:
I need to create a custom hook that I can reuse across multiple pages, in which the hook will fetch a list of data from the BE.

Old project implementation:
I have a customHook() which I call in a useEffect() within a page (dashboard). The customHook includes an async function to fetch data:
// hooks/customHook.tsx

export const getList = async () => {
   const res = await Service.getAll("list");
   ....
}

// pages/customHook.tsx

const Dashboard: FunctionComponent = () => {
   const { getList } = useCustomHook()

   useEffect(() => {
      getList()
   },[])

   return (...);
};

export default Dashboard;

I have a services folder where I have a generic in between function that calls the api handler:
// service/general.ts

export const getAll = async (endpoint) => {
    const url = new URL(`/api/get/${endpoint}`, window.location.origin);
   const res = await fetch(url);

   return res;
}

then on the pages/api/get/list.ts there is a handler function that does the request to the BE, something like this:
// pages/api/get/list.ts

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const jwt = getCookie("token", { req, res });
  const url = req.url?.replace("/api/get", "");

  const result = await fetch(`${process.env.url}${url}`, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${jwt}`,
      },
    });

  return res.status(200).json(result.data);
}


New project:
structure:
/src
  /components
  /hooks
    customHook.tsx
  /services
    general.ts
  /utils
  /app
    /dashboard
       page.tsx
    ...

I created a custom hook like mentioned above. I also created a service function like the above. My current issue is that I'm not sure how to convert the handler function to the app router system. I tried creating a similar app/api folder but the getAll() function was not reaching the handler.
Where does the handler should be considering that I may need to access it from different pages / hooks?
